# Modify light source so it will only create highlights and not reach into shadowy crevices?

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, workflow, compositing-nodes, light

My model has many protrusions and crevices.  I am satisfied with the shadow that currently exists in the crevices, but the protrusions need more highlight to create a sense of volume.  How can I adjust a light source so it only effects the protrusions and does not reach further into the crevices? As in, the light "falls off" at a designated point.  The goal is to make highlights with soft edges.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: related?: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/how-can-i-cast-artificially-darker-shadows

Comment: somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24321/add-contrast-or-saturation-to-render

Comment: You can adjust the Falloff type of the light source and increase the Soft Size

Comment: @Denis: I am using Cycles.

Comment: @WishyQ In lamp settings try to increase the size, higher value will make the shadow edges softer.